# Unmanaged C++ encrypted string into C# byte[]

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, encryption, marshalling

I have an unmanaged C dll I call from a C# class library that encrypts a string value into an encrypted string that contains non-ascii characters.  I need to take the data and write its binary values to a file, but C# treats text as `string` rather than a `byte[]`.

The encrypted value commonly contains special characters (`\r`, `\O`, etc).  When I do this converting the returned string to C# using some type of codeset (ascii, utf-7, utf-16) it writes the special character values as the Windows interpreted values instead their actual binary representation.

My question is how can I pull the data from the unmanaged dll into a `byte[]` rather than a string so I can write that to file using the `BinaryWriter`?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what kind of string it is and what's the encoding? (I mean the original string)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want Encoding.GetBytes() probably with UTF8?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the ASCIIEncoding class? It should turn any UTF-8 characters into the ascii character for '?'

[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx)

**Usage**

```
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] encodedBytes = ascii.GetBytes(unicodeString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using P/Invoke? Hmm... Perhaps the specifying [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.*)] would help.
Also, you could create an intermediary C function that instead exposes the encrypted data as (void *). That should be easier to get into a byte[].